# How can I produce a list of solutions for a function which is updated with updated variables using for loop?

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I need to loop over a set of equations, solving for X and adding the new X value to the old X value at each step. The output I need is a list `{x1, x1 + x2, x1 + x2 + x3, etc...}` where `xn` is the solution to the n`th equation.

I have tried to do this using a `For` loop but I am getting errors. Here is a simplified version of my code:

> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
>
> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
>
> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of $RecursionLimit::reclim will be
>   suppressed during this calculation. >>

How can I get the result I want? I am using *Mathematica* 7

Comment: Please try write a **Minimal** self-contained non-working example showing your problem

Comment: This is exactly the same problem he posted a couple of days ago, got a long string of people trying to help him, he could not get example solutions including input and output to run on his machine, he deleted his question and posted it again. Looking at my, and other's, comments in that deleted question explain most or all his misunderstandings in his code and data.

Comment: You should **work** and design the example. Otherwise I doubt somebody will be able to help you.

Comment: I think I already gave all the examples. What else are you expecting me to provide more? Could you please give me the example for the example you are asking for?

Comment: You have quite a few conceptual errors in your code, but it's difficult to show them in such a mess. Design a simpler equation using only two lists. As an example the problems in your code `X = X + X` isn't a "condition"

Comment: I added the brief version of my question below the main question in the question sheet above. Thanks.

Comment: Bill: I deleted the post and re-posted it since nobody was paying attention with no vaild answer. Sorry if that bothered you, but that's it.

Comment: It would have been better to edit the original question to address why that answer was no good for you. Editing bumps the question - giving it more visibility - and it isn't considered rude, whereas deleting and reposting when people have already invested effort in trying to help you *is* rude.

Comment: As for actually answering the question, it would help a lot if you stated what output you are expecting. Do you just need the sum of all the solutions for X? Or perhaps a list of `{1st solution, 1st + 2nd solution, 1st + 2nd + 3rd, etc...}`

Comment: Simon Woods: Yes. I am expecting the same thing you are describing.

Comment: I have done a major edit to your question to clarify and simplify it. I believe it is now answerable so will vote for it to be reopened.

Comment: Simon Woods: I thought you were going to give me the answer. Unfortunately, I can't vote since I am new here and do not have enought reputation.

Comment: Simon Woods: In addition, sorry but since Bill was giving a rude comment, I thought the atmosphere here was rude so I thought deleting the question was ok at that moment.

Comment: Simon Woods: Oh, sorry so you said you will vote for it to be reopened. Thank you. Then how can I get notified when the question is reopened?

Comment: So what do you need more from me to have the solution for this question..?

Comment: No one was rude or ignoring this individual. Several different people posted explanations of fundamental misunderstandings in his code. None of those helped. I posted a small example solution. The poster said it didn't work. Someone else looked at it and said there was no problem in my code. I finally asked if he wanted my complete code posted and he replied yes. I repeatedly checked that and posted it. He couldn't run it. I checked it again and he couldn't run it. I finally apologized and said I couldn't help him any more. No one was rude to him. We simply gave up trying. Show the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a table of the individual solutions like this:

```
solutions = Table[
   X /. Solve[(MM[[K + 2]])*X + (MM[[K + 2]]*R[[K + 2]]) == 0, X][[1]],
   {K, 9}]
```

Then use [`Accumulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html) to give the final desired result

```
Accumulate[solutions]
```